# MVC3: Geting values of cloned objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, model, clone

I have a drop down list with options from a model; and I want to add a similar drop down list when the user clicks on a button. My drop down list and button are defined as

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="id">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.mymodel)
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="JSFunc()"/>
```

And the function, JSFunc() is

```
var control = document.getElementById('id').cloneNode( true );
document.getElementById( 'parent' ).appendChild( new );
```

How can I get the value of the clone objects from the controller?

Comment: `DropDownListFor` requires property selector and select list. Also your cloned select element should have another name.

Comment: what do you mean by another name? Do you mean I should set an id for each one? and If so, how do I go about retrieving the values of each clone objects? Thanks

Comment: When form is submitted data is passed as name-value pairs for elements. If you cloned your option element, than your form has two option elements with same name.

Comment: ok, thanks. I can provide different names for the objects. But I am still stucked at retrieving them since I do not know ahead how many clone objects I will be retrieving, hence cannot pre-crate parameters for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `name` attribute of a newly-created `<select>` to something unique that matches a parameter name in your controller.

(or parameter property name, or anything else depending on the model binder and your situation)

Comment: Thanks. But the button may be clicked several times, so I do not know beforehand how many times this will be clicked, so it is difficult to set up a parameter for each cloned object.

Comment: You can name them `x[0]`, `x[1]` etc, then as far as I remember you should be able to use `string[] x` as a parameter. But MVC generally allows to do things nicely, so depending on your situation it might be more reasonable to make a custom model binder to make controller cleaner.